# Using rpy2 for inline rmagic with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, r, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, rpy2

I am trying to use inline rmagic with jupyter notebook, but have had an extremely difficult time trying to get it to work.

Whenever I try to load `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/MyName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site
   packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so, 2): Library not loaded: liblzma.5.dylib
   Referenced from: /Users/MyName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
   packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so
   Reason: image not found
```

I have tried installing it with `pip`, tried installing it with `conda install -c r rpy2`.

Beside this rpy2 issue, I *was* able to set up R and Jupyter notebook so that I can create a new notebook with R, so it doesn't seem to be an R/Jupyter communication issue.

I am running:

```
OS X (El Capitan)
Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.1.1 (x86_64)
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) (located as in /Users/myName/anaconda/bin)
rpy2 2.8.3 (located in /Users/myName/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/)
```

Is there any way to get `rpy2` to work with Jupyter notebook these days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by reinstalling anaconda, and installing `rpy2` through conda:

```
conda install rpy2
```

This will install `R` and lots of dependencies for anaconda. Use this `R` and not the system `R`. The `PATH` should be automatically updated after anaconda is installed, but just in case, make sure to prepend anaconda:

```
setenv PATH /Users/myName/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

It *critical* that `rpy2` be able to find the `Renviron` file, which should be newly installed within anaconda. I found mine here (I just searched for it using spotlight):

```
/Users/myName/anaconda2/lib/R/
```

which I then made into the `R_HOME` variable that `rpy2` requires to find `Renviron`. I also specified my username:

```
setenv R_HOME /Users/myName/anaconda2/lib/R/
setenv R_USER myName
```

(note that `which R` will return `/Users/myName/anaconda2/bin/R/`, but this is NOT `R_HOME`. This tripped me up for ages).

Answer (score 0):

This is looking like a conda issue to me (lzma present at build time, but missing at run time).

> Is there any way to get rpy2 to work with Jupyter notebook these days?

Probably more than one way to achieve it, but the docker container mentioned on the front page (http://rpy2.bitbucket.org/) is getting all pieces together in one step.